# Empty set returned from query

Tags: mysql

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a table hospital:

`Nurse + Year   + No.Patients

A001  |2000  |  23 

A001  |2001  |  30 

A001  |2002  |  35 



B001  |2000  |  12 

B001  |2001  |  15 

B001  |2002  |  45 
 


C001  |2000  |   50 

C002  |2001  |   59 

C003  |2002  |   69 

etc`

What I am trying to do is work out which nurse 
had the greatest increase of patients for the years 2000 - 2002.

Clearly B001 did as her patients increased from 12 to 45 and increase of 33
and what I am trying to produce is the result `B001 | 33`.

This is what I have so far:

```
select a.nurse,a.nopats from hospital as a
  join
    ( select nurse,max(nopats)-min(nopats) as growth
        from hospital where year between 2000 and 2002 group by nurse ) as s1
  on a.nurse = s1.nurse and a.nopats = s1.growth
  where year between 2000 and 2002;
```

but all I get returned is an empty set.

I think I need an overall max(nopats) after the join.

Any help here would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT nurse, (max(nopats) - min(nopats)) AS growth
  FROM hospital
 WHERE year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2002
 GROUP BY nurse
 ORDER BY growth DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Result: B001 | 33 due to LIMIT 1; just leave it away if you want more results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT nurse, MAX(nopats) - MIN(nopats) AS Growth
  FROM hospital 
 WHERE year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2002
 GROUP BY nurse
 ORDER BY Growth
```

That should do it. Let me know if thats what you needed.